How to serialize nested object in symfony
I have the next class
#[Assert\Cascade]
class PropertyPromotionDto
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $name,
        #[Assert\NotBlank(message: 'Не может быть пустым')]
        private int $value,

        #[Context([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d H:i'])]
        private DateTimeImmutable $date,

        private NestedDto $nestedDto,

        /** @var NestedDto[] */
        private array $nestedDtos,

        private Phone $phone
    ) {
    }


    
class NestedDto
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Assert\NotBlank(message:"Не должен быть пустым")]
        private string $author,

        private int $age,
        private ?DateTimeImmutable $date = null,
        private ?Phone $phone,
    ){
    }
}

}

And i have the next json
       {
            "name":"Mane",
            "value":42,
            "nestedDto": {"author": "Jane", "age": 35, "date":"2023-09-12"},
            "nestedDtos": [
                {"author": "",  "age": 20, "date":"2023-09-12"},
                {"author": "Pane", "age": 22}
            ]
        }

When i try to deserialize it, i catch error. I tried use flex serializer and flex like below
$encoder = [new JsonEncoder()];
            $extractor = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
            $normalizer = [new ArrayDenormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractor)];
            $serializer = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);

            return $serializer->deserialize($data, $type, $format);

Failed asserting that exception of type "The type of the "date" attribute for class "App\Dto\NestedDto" must be one of "App\Dto\DateTimeImmutable" ("string" given)."
Help, please

It was my fault.
Error says "must be one of App\Dto\DateTimeImmutable"
I just forget import DateTimeImmutable in my class.

Your context specifies the format via
#[Context([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d H:i'])]

You will need your JSON to comply to this format:
       {
            "name":"Mane",
            "value":42,
            "nestedDto": {"author": "Jane", "age": 35, "date":"2023-09-12 00:00"},
            "nestedDtos": [
                {"author": "",  "age": 20, "date":"2023-09-12 00:00"},
                {"author": "Pane", "age": 22}
            ]
        }


I upd answer.
NestedDto date dont have any context
